# Nothing happens when trying to upgrade from Linux Mint 12 to 13

Tags: linux, upgrade, linux-mint, apt-get

I am trying to upgrade from Linux Mint 12 to 13 using apt-get. After running the following commands, nothing seems to happen. I am fairly new to linux, what am I doing wrong?

```
user@olympus /etc/default $ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

user@olympus /etc/default $ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: You have to configure the new repositories in `/etc/apt`sources.list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clem, the Linux Mint dev, [recommends](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2) a different method to upgrade. Mint has a few specialized tools that make porting your data and settings to a new installation much easier.

Doing a clean install is generally a good idea. An update *may* go smoothly but you are also likely to have problems. If you do, the comments [here](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/62) may help.

Having said that, if you *still* want to use apt, edit (as root, `sudo`) your `/etc/apt/sources.lst` to point to the latest release:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ maya main upstream import
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise partner
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ precise free non-free
```

Save the file and then run the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Finally, reboot your computer.